Why did the root file system become RO?
Approximately once every 2 months, the remote dedicated server stops working.
The logs show that all logs stop being written at the same time.
Can't connect via ssh. The server responds, but immediately drops the connection.
ssh -vvv xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx
OpenSSH_9.3p1 Ubuntu-1ubuntu3.3, OpenSSL 3.0.10 1 Aug 2023
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config
debug1: /etc/ssh/ssh_config line 19: include /etc/ssh/ssh_config.d/*.conf matched no files
debug1: /etc/ssh/ssh_config line 21: Applying options for *
...
Welcome to Ubuntu 22.04.4 LTS (GNU/Linux 5.15.0-107-generic x86_64)
...
/bin/bash: Input/output error                    <-!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!
...
debug3: send packet: type 1
Connection to 31.184.218.159 closed.
Transferred: sent 4268, received 4732 bytes, in 0.2 seconds
Bytes per second: sent 17897.8, received 19843.6
debug1: Exit status 1

A reboot through the hosting admin panel restores the server.
It’s as if the root file system became read only, but I don’t understand how to confirm my guess and fix it.
$ sudo smartctl -a /dev/nvme0
...
SMART overall-health self-assessment test result: PASSED
...
SMART/Health Information (NVMe Log 0x02)
Critical Warning:                   0x00
...
Available Spare:                    100%
...
Percentage Used:                    1%
...
Error Information (NVMe Log 0x01, 16 of 64 entries)
No Errors Logged


$ sudo smartctl -a /dev/nvme1
...
SMART overall-health self-assessment test result: PASSED
...
SMART/Health Information (NVMe Log 0x02)
Critical Warning:                   0x00
...
Available Spare:                    100%
...
Percentage Used:                    2%
...
Error Information (NVMe Log 0x01, 16 of 64 entries)
No Errors Logged


How to ensure that the server does not stop working anymore?
Access to the server only via ssh.

So, my money's on the SSD having a hangup. SSDs are only human. (They're not, but their firmware authors very much are, and worse, the people hiring them and putting them under pressure are.) Hence, I'm afraid this calls for hardware replacement. If a company pays you to maintain that server, it might be easier to justify a couple 100€ spend in SSDs rather than you debugging this for long – worst case, it wasn't the SSDs, and then you have spare SSDs lying around.
Anyways, without more logging, nothing can be inferred. Since it seems your storage suddenly stops, we need to figure out whether

The whole system just stops working altogether or
The storage system crashes, leading to logs no longer being written.

(I think it's the second, because SSH still runs.)
So, you need to move your logging from the potentially failing storage to some other system, not affected by whatever is causing your outage.
So, since you're on Ubuntu 23.10 (by the way, 24.04 is an LTS version: maybe update now?), find a second machine that's reliable enough to carry logs for a few days. Install Ubuntu (version doesn't matter as long as recent enough, so I'd personally go for Ubuntu 24.04)
sudo apt install systemd-journal-remote
sudo systemctl enable systemd-journal-remote.{socket,service}
sudo systemctl start systemd-journal-remote

on that server; if you've set up firewalling, open a TCP port 19532 for incoming connections (I honestly think you can't reconfigure that). On your server with the hiccups, also install systemd-journal-remote and start the client service:
sudo apt install systemd-journal-remote
sudo systemctl enable systemd-journal-upload

You'll then want to create your own TLS certificate pair using openssl (so that nobody can take the place of your log server and receive confidential logs). You don't have to (can use http instead of https), but please don't send unencrypted logs across the internet, please. (A wireguard tunnel might work, but then you need to make sure that the upload client and the receiving service require the wireguard interface to be up before it's started).
On the client, set the URL= property in/etc/systemd/journal-upload.conf to point to your server (https://logserver.example.com:19532, or whatever host you use).

If you want to do this for a one-off, instead of systemd-remote, you can install systemd-journal-gateway, then systemctl enable systemd-journal-gatewayd.socket, reboot. You can then be as complacent as running curl 'http://failingserver.example.com:19531/entries?follow' | tee logs.txt on a different machine in a tmux window
